# In "Date Format" section, what code makes the date relative?

Tags: php, date, format

This code will show the date of publishing like: 4:30 10/7/2015

I want the date be like:

2 hours and 15 minutes ago

[image]

this setting is on showcase modules ("news show pro GK4" in this case) for showing your recent articles with the date of publishing.

Comment: To get only hours and minutes, change the value to `H i`

Comment: but " H:i " will show it like : " 01:32 "
I want " X hours ago "

Comment: Try `H hours and i minutes ago`

Comment: where is this setting? You will need to use a template override

Comment: This setting is on showcase modules, for showing your recent articles, in this case "News show pro GK4" where this date appears to show the publish date of your article where I want it to show the relative time of it.